# How to set offset path in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

How to set offset path in UWP? Using `CreateExpressionAnimation`, for example.

I have four images with static positions and I need other image to jump over those four one at time with animation.

Currently I'm using `CreateVector3KeyFrameAnimation` and changing the offset across the four images but I need an arc effect.

[image: Hand drawn depiction of requested animation]

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://twitter.com/justinxinliu/status/820941609655144449)? A curved motion?

Comment: Like that. The [illustration](http://imgur.com/a/IUViM) can help to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with 3 timelines in a storyboard - 1 x-axis translation with no easing that lasts the full duration of the animation, and then 2 y-axis translations one after the other each lasting half the animation time, first one using CircleOut easing (to the height of the arc) followed by the next using a CircleIn easing (back to 0).

Answer (score 0):

I test this with the code below:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="ImageStoryboard">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageTransform"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
        Duration="0:0:12" 
        EnableDependentAnimation="True" 
        RepeatBehavior="Forever">

        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="378" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="549" KeyTime="0:0:3"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="720" KeyTime="0:0:6"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="890" KeyTime="0:0:9"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame Value="378" KeyTime="0:0:12"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        Storyboard.TargetName="ImageTransform"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
        Duration="0:0:3" 
        EnableDependentAnimation="True" 
        RepeatBehavior="Forever">

        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="606" KeyTime="0:0:0">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="500" KeyTime="0:0:1.5">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>

        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame Value="606" KeyTime="0:0:3">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseIn" />
            </EasingDoubleKeyFrame.EasingFunction>
        </EasingDoubleKeyFrame>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Image x:Name="Image" ...>
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ImageTransform" />
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

Comment: You can also do this with composition if you want, using EasingFunctions generated from this class: https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/blob/master/SamplesCommon/SamplesCommon/PennerEquationBuilder.cs